# jq and bash : get a specific value in json when other key value pair matches

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to parse a JSON file to get a specific value where the condition is another key/value pair, but I don't know how to handle this (I am not a developer). For example, I get this JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": "c490ffaf-92ea-4a29-9614-ab36a088f366",
        "clientId": "account",
        "name": "${client_account}",
        "rootUrl": "${authBaseUrl}",
        "baseUrl": "/realms/test1/account/",
        "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    },
    {
        "id": "2daa32334-24322-4a29-43242-423223",
        "clientId": "swap",
        "name": "${client_swap}",
        "rootUrl": "${authBaseUrl}",
        "baseUrl": "/realms/test/swap/",
        "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    },
    {
        "id": "e22112-11111-4a329-22211-333312",
        "clientId": "broker",
        "name": "${client_broker}",
        "rootUrl": "${authBaseUrl}",
        "baseUrl": "/realms/test/broker/",
        "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    },
]
```

I want the value of "id" (c490ffaf-92ea-4a29-9614-ab36a088f366 in this example) from the block where the value from "clientId" is "account"

How to do that kind of thing with jq and bash?

Comment: You can use `jq -r 'map(select(.clientId == "account") | .id)[0]'` ([try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/NvD_gPIAj7)). If you have further questions please take a look at jq's [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and attempt to came up with your own solution before asking if you get stuck, questions asking for code without showing effort aren't well received on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In case there’s more than one occurrence, it might be wise to use the following query:

```
.[]
| select(.clientId == "account")
| .id
```